# Paragraph with border and padding splitted in two pages on print version

Tags: html, css, printing

Heres is my markup:

```
<div class="row admin-details-blocks">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><strong>Tipo: </strong>PF</p>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><strong>Email: </strong>teste@teste.com</p>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

On `<p>` tags, I'm using some padding, margim-bottom and a border:

```
.admin-details-blocks p {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #ac8c58;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

But on print version of page, some paragraph are split in two pages on Google Chrome, like this:

[image]

I try add `page-break-inside: avoid;` to `<p>` and to `.admin-details-blocks` class without any success: